# Icons in Activity Monitor?

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix

[image]

In the above image some processes have "icons" beside their names. What characteristic must a process meet to have an "icon" beside its name? Note the defining characteristic is **not** simply being in the Applications folder since several processes location in the Applications folder don't have the icon.

In addition how can I check if a PID meets the defining criteria in Objective-C? (Using Cocoa on OSX)

Comment: I think only `.app` processes have an icon. Can you explain more about what you want to do?

Comment: @woz I am trying to create an activity monitor that requires this info. I don't think .app is a type of process - its an folder containing several other processes.

Comment: When I open Activity Monitor, there's a drop down at the top. When I select "Windowed Processes", processes show up if and only if they have an icon. I'm not sure if that's any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think only applications that appear with their icon in the dock when you open them do have an icon in the activity monitor.

Comment: What kind of process must a process be to have an icon in the dock? This answer doesn't address my question.

Answer (score 1):

Applications that have "checked in" with Launch Services as a UI app get icons. Technically speaking, anything that ends up calling `LSApplicationCheckIn` will get one, but that's not a call you can make yourself.

If you run a standard `NSRunLoop`, or even initialize `NSApplication` (`[NSApplication sharedApplication]`) you should get it.

My question is: what are you doing that you're *not* getting it?